# ImageMagick crashing for JPEG with incorrect density value

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, dpi

I am trying to convert an image with ImageMagick. I am cropping and resampling to 112 DPI:

```
convert myimg.jpg -crop 1024x683+0+0 -resize 100% -resample 112 downsample.jpg
```

A script runs through many images of varying DPI and downsamples them.

However, a particular file has gummed up the script. Somehow, the file has a DPI of 1 (?!?) So it ends up trying to sample it up to 112 from 1, and the attempt eats up all my RAM and hangs the script.

```
identify -verbose myimage.jpg 
Image: myimage.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1024x683+0+0
  Resolution: 1x1 
  Print size: 1024x683
```

**Is there an argument/flag I can use with ImageMagick to prevent this from happening, maybe something that tells it to only downsample?**

Comment: 112 and 1 what?  I'm thinking maybe you need to specify units.  `-units pixelsperinch `  Might be something more here too: http://superuser.com/questions/479197/i-want-to-change-dpi-with-imagemagick-without-changing-the-actual-byte-size-of-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could your error be related to...

> For formats which do not support an image resolution, the original resolution of the image must be specified via -density on the command line prior to specifying the resample resolution.

JPEG I know supports resolution but maybe its wrong in the EXIF header or somehow ambiguous / confused with embedded thumbnail (again, maybe the unit is assumed).  I'd look more closely at the [`-density`] argument (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density) and how it relates to resolution and density on certain formats.

As for getting your script working.  Seems you might want to break the operations out into more individual actions?  If you can't satisfy the `convert` with using `-density` I would look at testing for the case you know fails and just skipping.  Could parse the results of `identify` or just the failure of the `convert`.  You are executing these in shell calls from PHP yes?

Comment: that makes sense. Actually, imagemagick is smart enough to let you do it all in one line, so for `convert -density 300 myimg.jpg -crop 1024x683+0+0 -resize 100% -resample 112 downsample.jpg` it knows the first part is setting the input resolution and the second part is setting the output resolution, and it gets the job done!

Comment: in general, yeah, the approach of analyzing identify will ultimately have to be used, but setting the density flag fixes this particular situation.